# An Olympiad Geometry question

Tags: geometry, contest-math

this is an Olympiad geometry question . I have been trying it for a long time but can’t come up with something useful to solve the problem . Here’s the question :

Let F be an interior point on the side BA of an acute angled triangle CBA . Let the circumcircle of triangle CFB intersect CA again at D ( not C ) and the circumcircle of triangle CFA intersect CB again at E ( not C ) . Let CF , BD and AE intersect the circumcircle of triangle CBA again at F1 , D1 and E1 . Let I and I1 be the incenters of the triangle FDE and F1D1E1 . Prove that D , E , I , I1 are concyclic .

The figure’s not given in the question . It’s so much that I am literally completely messed up . Anybody with a solution or even an approach would be welcome .

Edit : people I would have shared my approach if there was any . You can try out the question yourself - it’s really challenging ( I mean it’s a Olympiad question of course ) . I started off by drawing the figure but it couldn’t help me one bit and instead messed me up more . So here I am :)

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE, when posting questions, please be sure to write as much as you can on what you tried, your thoughts and why you think you got stuck.  It's really helpful for your learning process and also helps people guide you in a direction similar to your current thought process if possible

Comment: @iYOA Sure mate - thanks for the info . I will keep that in mind while posting the next question .

Comment: @iYOA Sorry to be troubling you . But I am curious as to why my question has a negative 1 mark . Did I make a mistake anywhere ?

Comment: @Mathgeek I think the -1 is probably because you didn't say what you already tried. Mathematical correctness is actually one of the less important factors in MSE questions :)

Comment: @SebastianMonnet but I had told that I was completely messed up right . I will be honest - the figure was so intimidating itself that I could do nothin but stare at the question . I asked my colleagues , friends and many others but to no avail . I was really curious for the solution , so I cam here out of despair . ( I tried the question much before coming here but with no apparent success ) .

Comment: @Mathgeek To be clear, I wasn't the one who downvoted your question. I do think it's maybe a little harsh, and I'm just explaining why I think it happened. In future, it might be worth explaining in the question what you just said in your comment, so it's really clear that you're not just being lazy. By the way, another potential reason I've just noticed for the -1 is that you didn't use MathJax to format it. Writing $F_1D_1E_1$ is a lot nicer than F1D1E1.

Comment: Please explain which Olympiad this is taken from, and possibly add a figure.

Comment: @SebastianMonnet I will surely do that . Thanks again for your help .

Comment: @Intelligentipauca this question is taken from INMO 2022 . I have a figure but not worth sharing it ( too messed up ) . I recommend it’s best if you draw the question yourself .

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Possibly from IOQM 2022 (National Olympiad for the selection of Indian team of IMO).

Comment: INMO is being held today, hence people should avoid answering.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I see , my friend gave it to me today afternoon . And I couldn’t help but think about it . So I asked here . If it’s wrong to do so pls let me know - I will take it down .

Comment: Sigh negative 3 - I tired my best to reform the question . Answered all the queries . And still people are downvoting me ..

Comment: @Mathgeek oh I see, so you're asking for a friend. If it's a math contest problem, it's best to wait a bit before posting online.  Generally not a good idea to post on the same day of the competition. Also I think you will find better luck posting this problem on Art of Problem Solving as that community is more geared towards contest math.   As to what you wrote, saying "I started off drawing the figure but got stuck" is not what I meant.  It'll be really helpful for you if you go into specifics like "i got stuck because..." or I was thinking of this theorem,,, Or I tried to show this..etc...

Comment: You can get into specifics a lot more than you realize. And it'll also help clarify your thinking so much more. You'll be really happy you did

Comment: @iYOA yes mate , I guess I understood  where I went wrong . Will keep that in mind while posting the next question . Also thanks again for your advice . Really appreciate it!

Comment: The "official" solution is now available [here](https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Part_B_2022_Solutions_revised.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove stronger conclusion $C,D,E,I,I_1$ are concyclic

To prove $C,D,E,I$ are concyclic, we prove that

> $\angle DIE+\angle DCE=180^\circ$

> $\angle DCE=180^\circ -\angle EFA=180^\circ -\angle DFB=180^\circ -\frac 12 (\angle EFA+\angle DFB)=180^\circ -\frac 12 (180^\circ +\angle DFE)=90^\circ -\frac 12 \angle DFE=180^\circ -\angle DIE$

To prove $C,D,E,I_1$ are concyclic, firstly we prove that $I_1$ is also the intersection of $AE,BD$ ,which equivalent to

$\angle AE_1D_1=\angle AE_1F_1,\angle BD_1E_1=\angle BD_1F_1$.

$\angle BD_1E_1=\angle BAE_1=\angle BCF_1=\angle BD_1F_1$

$\angle AE_1D_1=\angle AE_1F_1$ can be proved in the same way.

Then we do a `c-center inversion` to all the point.
The conclusion that $C,D,E,I_1$ are concyclic equivalent to the following question.

$A,B,C,F$ are concyclic, $AF \cap BC=E$ , $EF \cap CA= D$ ,prove that the intersection of circumcircle of $\Delta CBD$ and circumcircle of triangle $CAE$, point $G$, is on $DE$.

Accurately, $G$ is the Miquel point of complete quadrangle $G,D,A,F$ and $G,E,B,F$ are concyclic. So $\angle FGE+\angle FGE=180^\circ -\angle FAD+180^\circ -\angle FBE=180^\circ$ .

Q.E.D.

> `I'm freshman to both English and MSE. My apology for bad reading reading experience.`

Images.

> For original problem.
> [image]

> After doing inversion.
> [image]

---

Prove that $C,D,E,I_1$ are concyclic without doing inversion after proving that $I_1$ is also the intersection of $AE,BD$.

$\angle CEA=\angle CFA=180^\circ -\angle CFB=180^\circ -\angle CDB.$

I did inversion in order to simplify the graph but seems that I make it more complicated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Kurippy Hey mate thanks very much for your answer , but I was wondering if you had a diagram . If yes could you share it ?

Comment: @Math geek Yes.I add them to my answer.

Comment: @Kurippu dude , everything is perfect but I couldn’t follow the inversion step . Could you solve the problem without using inversion .

Comment: @Math geek I did so.

Comment: Yes mate - perfect . Appreciate your help